# Issue with Object's Method when unmarshalling?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I would like to know why my unmarshalling process cause some troubles:

1. I save my java object in a xml file.
2. I load my java object from the xml file

Once that's done, strange behaviour occurs in the method of my java object (ClassMain.java).

Indeed the `method isLogin()` **returns false just before it returns true** (ClassMain.java. Any ideas?

**MainClass**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Player p1 = new Player();
    p1.setLogin("p1");
    p1.setMdp("mdp1");      
    try {

        //Test : verify that player's login is 'p1' (return true)
        System.out.println(p1.isLogin("p1"));

        marshaling(p1);

        Player pfinal =unMarshaling();

        //Test : verify that player's login is 'p1' (return False ?why?)
        System.out.println(pfinal.isLogin("p1"));

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private static Player unMarshaling() throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Player.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Player player = (Player) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal( new File("C:/Users/Public/player.xml") );
    return player;
}   
private static void marshaling(Object o) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Player.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(o, new File("C:/Users/Public/player.xml"));
}}
```

**Player Class**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "joueur")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Player{

@XmlAttribute
private String login;

public Player() {
}
public String getLogin() {
    return this.login;
}
public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public boolean isLogin(String n){
    if(this.login == n)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
}
```

Comment: without further looking, please don't compare strings with the equal operator `if(this.login == n)`, use the `equals` method instead.

Comment: "returns false just before it returns true" - what does that mean? Do you get any exceptions or just strange behavior?

Answer (score 2):

`isLogin` makes identity comparison on `String` objects.

In the first case, you use several times the same String literal `"p1"`, and the `==` gives `true` because of the `String` pooling.

After unmarshalling, you get a new `String` which `equals` "p1", but won't be the same `String` object.

So use `equals` instead of `==` in your `isLogin` method.

See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Thanks you Berger !
Have a good day